# C# write all index of an array in differents WriteLines from txt file

Tags: c#, arrays, console

I have a `.txt` file with arrays that looks like this: [image: List of arrays]

After I have search for a match in an array, I want to `Console.WriteLine` each index of that array.

```
// Finder bestemt brugere
else if (brugervalg == "f")
{
    Console.Write("Hvad vil du søge efter?: ");
    string søgestreng = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

    // System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteLines2.txt = ",lines);
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {                                                                                                           
        if (line.Contains(søgestreng))
        {
                Console.WriteLine();  //want to list first index of array here
                Console.WriteLine();  //List next index here
                Console.WriteLine();  //So on
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains(søgestreng))
            {
                var values = line.Split(',');
                foreach (var value in values)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Instead of foreach? if yes, i just tried it and it wont spit anything out in console.

Comment: I replaced the code, but i wont spit anything out https://gyazo.com/9da45160f8b80840c0ecb0cef05b8643

Comment: On the screen shot you have
... if (lines[1] ...
Should be 
... if (lines[i] ...

Comment: ahh stupid mistake, sorry about that. Now it only writes match at index 2 but not the first from index...  https://gyazo.com/1d8df5604d8fb20621b02033be74fded

Comment: I don't understand your question anymore. That code only shows an index of the line match was found in.

Comment: Okay, let me explain. Lets say i search for a tlf nr (42541990) i want to list all the information in that array in different Console.WriteLine like this: Tlf nr: 42541990, name: David jajaja and so on. How would u do that? hope that explains it better :)

Comment: I've edited code according to your explanation. But that doesn't have anything to do with the indexes of arrays. You should edit your question.

Comment: Also instead of the foreach you can use "Number: " + values[0] or "Name: " + values[1]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! and sorry for the misunderstanding!